# Keep Divs at Bottom When Others are Expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to emulate gmail's compose window (you know the one that opens from the bottom right of your inbox). Well, when I have multiple windows, I'm having a hard time trying to keep the minimized windows positioned at the bottom of the screen.

See code pen for details 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaZrLB

Problem:
When both Window 1 and Window 2 are minimized, and you click on Window 1, the Window 2 titlebar lifts up rather than staying on the bottom of the screen.

HTML

```
<div class="bottomBar"><!--start bottomBar-->

   <div class="bottomWindow"><!--start bottomWindow-->
     <div class="titleBar bg-black color-white">
       <div class="fl">This is a titlebar</div>
       <i class="windowSize fa fa-angle-up fr"></i>
       <i class="windowSize hidden fa fa-angle-down fr"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="contentSection hidden">
       <p>Hello, this is content</p>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- end bottomWindow -->

  <div class="bottomWindow"><!--start bottomWindow-->
     <div class="titleBar bg-black color-white">
       <div class="fl">This is a titlebar</div>
       <i class="windowSize fa fa-angle-up fr"></i>
       <i class="windowSize hidden fa fa-angle-down fr"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="contentSection hidden">
       <p>Hello, this is content</p>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- end bottomWindow -->

</div> <!--end bottomBar -->
```

CSS:

```
/*global stuff*/
.hidden{display:none;}
.fr {float:right;}
.fl {float:left;}
.bg-black{background-color:black;}
.color-white{color:white;}

/* window stuff */
.bottomBar{position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;}
.bottomWindow {margin-right:20px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;float:left;}
.titleBar{padding:10px 20px;min-width:200px;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;}
.contentSection {padding:5px 20px;}
```

JS:

```
$(".titleBar").click(function(e) {
$(this).find('.windowSize').toggleClass("hidden");
$(this).next('.contentSection').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then setting the `bottomBar` `fixed` at bottom right. Set `bottomWindow` at the bottom right:

### Update:

***By adding a little javascript you can make it work as you want:***

```
putDivBottom('.bottomWindow');
$(".titleBar").click(function(e) {
 width1 = $(this).parent().width();
 right1 = $(this).css("right");
 console.log(width1); 
 $(this).find('.windowSize').toggleClass("hidden");
 $(this).next('.contentSection').toggleClass('hidden');
  setButtomDiv($(this).parent(),width1);
  console.log($(this).parent().width());
});

function putDivBottom(elementClass,width1){
  for(i=0;i<$(elementClass).length;i++){
  $(elementClass+":eq("+i+")").css({"right":(i)*260}); 
  }
}
function setButtomDiv(this1, width1){
  index1 = $(".bottomWindow").index(this1);
  if (width1==240){
     rightAdd = $(this1).width()-240;
  }
  else{
     rightAdd = 240 - width1;
  }
  for(i=index1+1;i<$(".bottomWindow").length;i++){
    value1=$(".bottomWindow:eq("+i+")");
    right1 = parseInt(value1.css("right"));
 value1.css({"right":rightAdd+right1+"px"});
  }
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPWqvB)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gaurav! But what happens when windows are dynamically added. How to deal with the style="right:260px" you've added?

Comment: By adding a little javascript we can deal with style="right:260px". I have elaborated in my answer how to deal with. Created a toggle like function which you can modify accordingly.

Comment: You are such a boss. Thanks Gaurav!